# amsthm LaTex package not found in R (3.2.6)

Tags: r, latex

I'm trying to compile a .Rnw file to PDF in RStudio using the amsthm package but keep getting the error "LaTex Error: File 'amsthm.sty' not found. Is amsthm not available on the latest version of R?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "It never is" -- R relies on external (La)TeX installations that are expected to be complete: texlive for Linux and macos, miktex for Windows. On my Ubuntu machine `amsthm.sty` comes with package `texlive-latex-base` ensuring it comes with every latex installation there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying Miktex for Windows and I've had the same problem: file 'amsthm.sty' not found. You can add it from the console, but it's not listed with that name. It's included in the amscls package.

Packages can be searched here: https://www.ctan.org/

Comment: I updated it and i still get tthe error.